# Phabricator can't upload some files on specific PCs

Tags: upload, phabricator

**Installation**: OS Debian 8.6 Jessie 
**Phabricator version**: 
phabricator 62cf4e6b95abbebc8ae2b1591039967651188c6e (Sat, Jan 14)
arcanist ade25facfdf22aed1c1e20fed3e58e60c0be3c2b (Fri, Jan 6)
phutil 9d85dfab0f532d50c2343719e92d574a4827341b (Fri, Jan 13)
**MySQL**: mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
**Apache2**: 
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built: Sep 15 2016 20:44:43
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:37
Server loaded: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.4

Storage is configured MySQL (storage.mysql-engine.max-size = 8388608) and localdisk (storage.local-disk.path is set).

Phabricator is setup like vhost with next config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phabricator.domain.com
   ServerAlias phab.domain.org

    DocumentRoot /home/repo/phabricator/phabricator/webroot/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/phabricator-error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/phabricator-access.log common
 <Directory "/home/repo/phabricator/phabricator/webroot">
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**The bug**:

[image: Few files upload]

After almost 2 year work with that installation of Phab we started to experience file upload problems. 5 users reported sporadically stalled upload files on 15-20-25% and freez. Network access to server is stalled. Must reset connection.
2 of users always have a problem with upload (Nor drag-and-drop way nor upload form). That appear in task edit and in File module. Testet with all available browsers - IE11, Chrome, Firefox.
Network recovers only by reset (enable/disable) of network adapter to brings back the network connection.
The size of files is from 500K to 2.5Mb. I thought is not a size critical - next time same file can be uploaded for few seconds.

The problem files on neighbour PC, same network, uploads fast and OK!

Apache2 logs and Phabricator logs not report any errors which is strange.
All recommended settings in apache2 conf and PHP values are setup to the highest possible timeout or files/upload size.

If it's needed more info/actions/logs can provide.

Comment: Resolved: Change in PHP upload size and permit Phabricator's URLs in enterprize AV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: Change in PHP upload size and permit Phabricator's URLs in enterprize AV